# What do we know absolutely?

Tags: knowledge

A frequent "starter question" for Self Inquiry is: "*What do you know for sure?*" How would Philosophy state, without question, what **we can and do know**?

I don't mean **everything that we know**, I mean, what are the 'axioms' (besides the Laws of Thought): things that anyone can be certain of from their own experience? What is a Philosophy starter kit? Can I come to those conclusions myself without any assistance? (Else it would be question-begging, because *someone* must have thought these things first...)

Someone asked: [What is Self Inquiry](http://www.sriramanamaharshi.org/teachings/instructions/), so see the linked page and this quote from Ramana Maharishi: "*When one persistently inquires into the nature of the mind, the mind will subside leaving the Self (as residue).*" Also this quote: "*The thought* 'who am I?' *will destroy all other thoughts, and like the stick used for stirring the funeral pyre, it will itself be burnt up in the end. Then, there will be Self-realization.*"

Comment: Cogito ergo sum, critical scepticism at its best (seriously, it cannot possibly go any further!) ;)

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking So, that is the sum of what we can and do know? (No cogito intended:-) Not sure why we didn't simply stop pursuing Philosophy at that point if it cannot tell us anything new. Personally, I find Self Inquiry to be fruitful in a way that Philosophy is not.

Comment: The problem of your question is that its too broad. After Descartes, Kant extended the sphere of knowledge in the strictest of senses and Fichte and Hegel did even moreso. And now look at what sciences claim to "know" nowadays. There are philosophical positions covering all of this, too. Therefore, it would like to ask you to narrow the scope.

Comment: Some of the issue you may be facing is that Philosophy's demands on the word "knowledge" are *vastly* more strict than any other field you come across (mathematics *may* be an exception).  By being more demanding, it can ask questions that other fields cannot.  For example, you say "self inquiry" is more fruitful than Philosophy.  What is "self inquiry?"  Can self inquiry explore what it, itself, is?  Soon one realizes that "self inquiry," itself, is a topic which is better described within Philosophy than by many other means.

Comment: Another example is that philosophy can tell you *exactly* what assumptions get made in science, permitting you to explore when those assumptions were reasonable, and when you need to consider an alternative to science because the assumptions become difficult for that particular topic.

Comment: @CortAmmon The point of Self Inquiry (the path by knowledge to Nonduality, there are other paths to it) is an infinite regress in to Self Inquiry. As Bart Marshall said, "*We are trying to maneuver the mind in to a position where it disappears.*"

Comment: @nocomprende How can a mind that has dissapeared know anything?

Comment: What Marshall says is a nice picture for what Hegel did in some sense 200 years ago, i.e. the becoming of the mind as having itself without mind-world dualism...

Comment: @CortAmmon The mind that has disappeared leaves the Self unimpeded in its ability to know. Transcending the Self is Nonduality. Only the *I* is left at that point. It can be transcended also, but not for long at a time, or by death. What "assumptions become difficult" in the study of consciousness and how does Philosophy address them?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Does Philosophy tell how to get to this state of awareness?

Comment: Not in the essentially esoteric sense you seem to have in mind. But Hegel's own pretense was leading the way to the mind having itself in its truth in his *Phenomenology of Mind*. It isn't quite conceivable in English translation, though.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Thank you for the pointer to further research. I think that Nonduality is not conceivable in any language, but that is why I asked here, to see if Philosophy covers any of the same ground as Self Inquiry, so I would know whom I was talking with.

Answer (score 1):

Much of philosophy actually engages in a stripping away of things that can be *known*.  In that respect it is similar to a field called Reverse Mathematics.  Normal mathematics typically tries to prove as much as they can using the assumptions given.  Reverse mathematics explores how few assumptions have to be made to make a proof.

Philosophy generally starts from as few assumptions as possible.  As Philip mentioned, "Cogito ergo sum" is a popular point because we have not found a way to reduce our minimum starting point to anything less than that without removing our ability to think about it.  Thus, when you ask "what can we know for sure," the answer is very small.

Your quote from Self Inquiry is an excellent case study:

> When one persistently inquires into the nature of the mind, the mind will subside leaving the Self (as residue).

How do you know this for sure?  Granted it's probably quite sage advice, but you talk about what we know *absolutely*.  How do we know persistent inquiry will yield the desired results?  Descartes explored a philosophical position related to this that resulted in the so called Cartesian Demon, where there isn't such a guarantee (or if such a guarantee does exist, we have to define the "Self," which is a tricky topic indeed).  There's a branch of philosophy known as physicalism which contents that the mind is actually an illusion!  There's philosophies where we all have freewill, and there are philosophies where every action we take is deterministic.

In the end, one chooses which axioms they wish to believe.  Perhaps, for you, Ramana Maharishi's quote *is* a good axiom, and you choose to accept it.  From there, there's bountiful bodies of philosophy going in the normal direction in the form of "If you assume X, here's the natural conclusions from X."  However, the initial assumption of X is always up to you.

If anything, philosophy points out that these assumptions *are* choices.  It explores worlds where those assumptions may not be valid, demonstrating that you are *choosing* a path, not being forced into one.  You ask the question, "Does Philosophy tell how to get to this state of awareness?"  The answer is no, it does not.  What it does do is give you a lot of advice on what the path *could* look like, and lets you decide which path to take.  It also gives you solid arguments as to *why* you should not simply assume a particular path will lead you to where you want to go.  You can *choose* the path of Self Inquiry.  And in doing so, you can search for the "Self," knowing there's a *huge* volume of philosophy dedicated to trying to answer questions regarding what the Self is and what it is not.  You may even find helpful directions where you never expected them.  Personally, I found Arne Naess's philosophy of the "ecological Self" very helpful for putting me on the path I have chosen.

Comment: As a general comment about teaching such as what I see of Self Inquiry: they are often very good at describing one particular path to a goal, and tend to be less effective at describing any state which is not perfectly on that path. Philosophy can be helpful for capturing the differences between where you are and the path you want to take, and suggesting ways to approach aligning yourself with your chosen path. Thus, it should be of no surprise that, if you are perfectly on the perfect path for you, you will find no reason to deviate from your perfect philosophy and explore other philosophies.

Comment: But it is very common to declare that nobody is perfect.

Comment: For me, the path is whatever takes a particular person to Nonduality. All paths by all people are valid, but some are more 'scenic' than others (slower). Self Inquiry is self-directed, therefore it does not make a person subject to anyone else's leading. You are closest to your own goal, so you know "God's Algorithm" (Rubik's Cube metaphor) for getting there. How Philosophy can show one's obstacles of thought to getting beyond thought is what I am asking about. Thought is only a tool, not a destination. "**You are not your mind, but it is yours to use.**" So, what *are* we then?

Comment: @nocomprende That is a commonly asked question.  You may consider altering it to "Does our path require us to know what we *are* in order to follow it?"  Knowledge is a tricky topic.  In philosophy, Epistomology is the study of knowledge, what knowledge *is*, what knowledge we can attain, etc.  The topic could fill hundreds of thousands of pages, all knowledge.  Or, one may realize that this is the way knowledge is, and choose a path that is less dependent on knowing anything in particular.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to hear more about your particular path, but this is not the venue for that. It seems you are saying that Philosophy is meant to be a sort of antidote to assumption, thought, and especially Religion (belief without sufficient evidence. It reminds me of this [poem by Marilyn Hacker](https://books.google.com/books?id=ge9cAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT122&lpg=PT122&dq=%22the+searing+curve+of+beauty%22&source=bl&ots=-ZVgTXyi0K&sig=yfjbVE22uRHnO3yJJVksA2lAo9Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3scq0zf3KAhUB8CYKHRsQBEUQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22the%20searing%20curve%20of%20beauty%22&f=false).

Comment: If you decide your path *does* require knowing something, philosophy can help you study what the effects of that knowledge are.  I don't know any specifics of Self Inquiry, but if I may use philosophy to tie it to many other approaches to achieve non-duality, many approaches actually get hung up on the *need* for a particular bit of knowledge.  Philosophy can be a helpful tool for letting go of that need without necessarily clinging to yet another piece of knowledge.

Comment: Philosophy can be thought of as an anditote, if you already presume you were on the right path and need to stay on it.  I'd be tempted to take a higher level view and say philosophies like Self Inquiry are *part* of philosophy as a whole.  Thus, naturally any time you step off the perfect path of Self Inquiry, you find yourself in the realm of philosophy.  Alternatively, you never left the realm of philosophy, you were there the whole time.  You were merely choosing to be selective about which regions of philosophy to consider.

Comment: Personally, because its the path I took, I recommend reading about Arne Naess's concept of the ecological self.  It does not answer what the Self *is*, but you may find the exploration he takes on his journey highly beneficial for helping you answer that question for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The question *What do we know absolutely?* is a hot topic or "evergreen" of philosophy, more specific of epistemology.

Descartes is a good example for a philosopher who made a new start. As you write, Descartes claimed to have found a new answer, see his *Meditations*. Another example is Kant with his claim of synthetic a priori knowledge, see his *Critique of Pure Reason*.

In general, all arguments proposed for knowledge concerning general facts have been questioned by later philosophers. The problem made a revolutionary turn during 20th century by Poppers principle of falsification: Broadly speaking, we can never prove that general statements are knowledge. But we can falsify such statements by giving a single counterexample. Then we have to design a new hypothesis which avoids the errors of the previous one. *We err upwards* (Gerhard Vollmer).

Popper's proposal - of course itself a hypothesis - abandons any attempt to find and to justify knowledge about general facts. Instead of obtaining knowledge we design and falsify hypotheses. The prototype of this method is the scientific method.

I consider it a remarkable fact, that we do not need knowledge, but successfully build applications on hypothetical scientific hypotheses, vulgo: theories.

A possible consequence of Popper’s insight is to abandon the search for “absolute” knowledge, being the search for a phantasm, and to invest into the design of better hypotheses.

Concerning *self inquiry* we know from cognitive psychology and from neuroscience, that we do not have access to most of our unconscious mental processes. At most, processes in the neocorthex can become conscious. But our decisional processes are triggered in deeper areas, e.g. in the limbic system. Also self inquiry, even by meditation, cannot enter into these regions.

We have to face the fact that all conscious experience is the result of complex and unconscious information processing. Terms like “the mind”, “the Self”, and “I” are aggregated concepts on a high level. I consider it necessary to find the neurobiological correlates of these concepts. Neuroscience has started to venture into these domains.

Comment: Thank you. Self Inquiry is said to be "a path of doubt, not a path of belief", so I think it accords with what you are saying. While it is true that perhaps we cannot go as far as LUCY and become aware of everything, it is possible to be more aware of experience, inward as well as outward. I am not sure what becoming aware of the neurological basis would really do for most people, any more than knowing a lot about the physics of sound would improve their experience of a Symphony. If they simply could listen with more clarity and presence, that would be sufficient.